# Working with 5 parameters (columns) csv file in TensorFlow

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow

I am having some trouble dealing with a CSV file that has 4 variables and 1 output. 
My error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\maric\Anaconda2\envs\python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py", line 458, in make_tensor_proto
    str_values = [compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values]   File "C:\Users\maric\Anaconda2\envs\python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py", line 458, in <listcomp>
    str_values = [compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values]   File "C:\Users\maric\Anaconda2\envs\python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\compat.py", line 65, in as_bytes
    (bytes_or_text,)) TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got tf.float32

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "insane.py", line 31, in <module>
    x = tf.Variable(tf.float32, [None, n_input])   File "C:\Users\maric\Anaconda2\envs\python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 200, in __init__
    expected_shape=expected_shape)   File "C:\Users\maric\Anaconda2\envs\python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 289, in _init_from_args
    initial_value, name="initial_value", dtype=dtype)   File "C:\Users\maric\Anaconda2\envs\python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 676, in convert_to_tensor
    as_ref=False)   File "C:\Users\maric\Anaconda2\envs\python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 741, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)   File "C:\Users\maric\Anaconda2\envs\python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 113, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)   File "C:\Users\maric\Anaconda2\envs\python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 102, in constant
    tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))   File "C:\Users\maric\Anaconda2\envs\python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py", line 462, in make_tensor_proto
    "supported type." % (type(values), values)) TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.dtypes.DType'> to Tensor. Contents: <dtype: 'float32'>. Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

And my code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = "insane.csv"
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["insane.csv"])

line_reader = tf.TextLineReader()
_, csv_row = line_reader.read(filename_queue)

record_defaults = [[0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0]]
sucrose, ye, kh2, mgso, out = tf.decode_csv(csv_row, record_defaults=record_defaults)


features = tf.stack(record_defaults)

#parameters
learning_rate = 0.0001
training_epochs = 5
batch_size = 3
display_step = 1
num_examples = 15

#NEtworkParameters

n_layer_1 = 6
n_layer_2 = 6
n_input = 5
n_classes = 10

x = tf.Variable(tf.float32, [None, n_input])
y = tf.Variable(tf.float32, [None])
x = tf.convert_to_tensor(x, dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=tf.float32)


def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases):
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)

    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)

    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer


weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_layer_1])),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_layer_1, n_layer_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_layer_2, n_classes]))
}

biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_layer_1])),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_layer_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}

pred = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = int(num_examples/batch_size)

        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x = []
            batch_y = []

            for iteration in range(1, batch_size):
                example, label = sess.run([features, out])
                batch_x.append(example)
                onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(label, tf.float32), depth=2)
                batch_y.append(onehot_labels)

                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
                avg_cost += c / total_batch

                if epoch % display_step == 0:
                    print ("Epoch:", '%04d' %(epoch+1), "cost=", \
                    "{:.9f".format(avg_cost))

    print ("Optimization Finished!")
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

My csv file is (Experimentals = Labels):

```
Sucrose;Yeast_extract;K2HPO4;MgSO4;Experimentals
35;1.0;1.25;0.5;7.97
65;1.0;1.25;0.5;15.22
35;2.0;1.25;0.5;9.53
65;2.0;1.25;0.5;12.60
35;1.0;1.75;0.5;9.44
65;1.0;1.75;0.5;13.16
35;2.0;1.75;0.5;9.81
65;2.0;1.75;0.5;11.65
35;1.0;1.25;1.0;8.47
65;1.0;1.25;1.0;14.05
35;2.0;1.25;1.0;9.50
65;2.0;1.25;1.0;11.70
35;1.0;1.75;1.0;7.09
65;1.0;1.75;1.0;11.10
35;2.0;1.75;1.0;6.69
65;2.0;1.75;1.0;10.44
20;1.5;1.5;0.75;6.29
80;1.5;1.5;0.75;14.88
50;0.5;1.5;0.75;12.25
50;2.5;1.5;0.75;10.38
50;1.5;1.0;0.75;10.65
50;1.5;2.0;0.75;9.50
50;1.5;1.5;0.25;10.16
50;1.5;1.5;1.25;10.65
50;1.5;1.5;0.75;11.13
50;1.5;1.5;0.75;11.50
50;1.5;1.5;0.75;11.10
50;1.5;1.5;0.75;10.99
50;1.5;1.5;0.75;10.98
50;1.5;1.5;0.75;11.03
```

I have tried to workout this and other errors for quite a while but I am stuck in a loop. Maybe my logic is wrong, so if it's not a problem with the code, I you be grateful if anyone could give me a link or an idea of how could I do that.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I tried to adapt the code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44426379/input-a-csv-file-into-tensorflow-to-construct-neural-network

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Minimize the code, provide the entire error message, and give us a data subset in a usable form.

Comment: If you have an environment with the libraries I imported, the code should run. I've tried to simplify the error message, but I'll post the entire error then. And I don't know exactly where is my error in the code, that is why I've pasted the non-simplified code.

Comment: I have also copied and pasted my .csv file to the question, perhaps that can be easier. I really tried to optimize and simplify my question, but that's a little bit difficult when you don't exactly know what you are dealing with

Comment: Much better; thanks.  I'll have to install TensorFlow on this machine before I can be of further use ...

Comment: tf.Variable(tf.float32, ...) is not how tensorflow variables work, and this is causing your stacktrace. Use something like tf.Variable(0.0, ...) (the first argument to the variable constructor is the value and not the type; look at the documentation for more information).